# NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element - Selenium webdriver using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

So, I know the issue due to countless hours of research. The only issue is that no one is basing their code like the way I do and/or are not clear on where/what to insert in my code. I know you need to do either a try/catch statement and/or to do the wait.until statement. I've tried both to no success, and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
require('chromedriver');
const selenium = require("selenium-webdriver");
const By = selenium.By;
const until = selenium.until;

const driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

driver.get("https://qa.chaplinq.org/LinQ/Account/SignIn");

const locators = {
    loginForm: By.id("login-form"),
    loginField: By.css("input#UserName"),
    loginPass: By.css("#login-form input[name='Password']"),
    signIn: By.css("form#login-form > footer > button"),
    createAcc: By.css("a#createAccountBtn"),
    applyfirstName: By.css("input#FirstName"),
    applylastName: By.css("input#LastName"),

function createAcc() {
    driver.findElement(locators.createAcc).click();

};

function firstName(text) {
    driver.findElement(locators.applyfirstName).sendKeys(text);
};

createAcc();
firstName("kevin");

[ERROR] node : (node:1896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to 
[ERROR] locate element: {"method":"css 
selector","selector":"input#FirstName"}
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + node index.js
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ((node:1896) 
Unh...put#FirstName"}:String) [], RemoteExcepti 
[ERROR]    on
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]   (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
[ERROR]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 
(7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 
[ERROR] 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[ERROR]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse 
(C:\users\kevin.yu\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:585:15)
[ERROR]     at parseHttpResponse (C:\users\kevin.yu\node_modules\selenium- 
webdriver\lib\http.js:533:13)
[ERROR]     at Executor.execute (C:\users\kevin.yu\node_modules\selenium- 
webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
[ERROR]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (node:1896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either 
[ERROR] by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by 
rejecting a promise which was not 
[ERROR] handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (node:1896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejections are deprecated. In the future, 
[ERROR] promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
process with a non-zero exit code.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: i can see exception is at   applyfirstName: By.css("input#FirstName")  
please provide html code for more clarification of this issue
is it like <input id='FirstName'> in HTML
Does your code clicks on Create Account 
It seems like failing while entering First Name field
You can give a try with XPATH as well

Comment: Sorry, i'm still pretty new to this. Thought I had everything. Here is the HTML code for function firstName(text):

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field First Name: must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '50'." data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-required="The First Name: field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">

Comment: @AshishKamble, Yes it is failing when it is looking for the first name field. I have tried By.id and By.xpath and both don't work. The only thing that was able to work for me was doing a setTimeout(function () {firstName("Kevin"); }, 5000) at the bottom, but i know that is not good practice and merely a shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

"NoSuchElementError" suggests that the element is not present (yet) in the HTML document. This can occur when some elements appear/disappear dynamically. When your Selenium scripts run faster than the element loads, the element is not visible yet and this error will be thrown.

In your case, does the element `input#FirstName` appear only after `input#FirstName` has been clicked?

If so, consider adding a [pause](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html#pause) or [wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#wait) function in between createAcc() and firstName()

Comment: I am looking at selenium's documentation that you provided me, and i'm still confused. Would you be able to provide what I need to insert between createAcc() and firstName()?

Answer (score 0):

Put a closing brace to close your "locators" object (syntax error)

Comment: If you want to use a try catch, you put the 'risky' code in the try block and then the error handling in the catch block. Example: 
    `try {
      createAcc();
      firstName("kevin");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

**Web Components / Shadow DOM elements**

The error occurs if trying to find elements in shadow DOMs (even if they are already on the page).

The `/deep/` and `::shadow` css selectors were deprecated and removed prior to this answer and so are not an option.

[This](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver) article (not mine) describes a workaround using `executeScript` in Java.

javascript example ;

Eg. using id values where you have a host/web component tag on the page with id "hostId" and you want an element inside it (which has already been rendered) with id "targetElementId" ;

```
async function getComponentElement(hostId,targetElementId){
    let host = await driver.findElement(By.id(hostId));
    let targetElement = await driver.executeScript(() => {            
            return arguments[0].shadowRoot.getElementById(arguments[1]);
        }
        ,host,targetElementId
    );    
    return targetElement ;
}

let element = await getComponentElement('hostId','targetElementId');
```